# NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable Error in Kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I've stumbled upon a 'NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable'-error in our Jupyter-notebook using this code:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from kafka.errors import KafkaError

def on_send_success(record_metadata):
    print(record_metadata.topic)
    print(record_metadata.partition)
    print(record_metadata.offset)

def on_send_error(excp):
    log.error('I am an errback', exc_info=excp)
    # handle exception

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('utf-8'))
INTERVAL =10
while True:
    data_points = get_realtime_stock('AAPL')
    data = {'updated_on': data_points['updated_on'], 'ticker': data_points['security']['ticker'] ,'last_price': data_points['last_price']}
    message = data_points
    producer.send('data1', value=data).add_callback(on_send_success).add_errback(on_send_error)
    time.sleep(INTERVAL)
```

Here the respective error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoBrokersAvailable                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-cab724428b84> in <module>
     11     # handle exception
     12 
---> 13 producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('utf-8'))
     14 INTERVAL =10
     15 while True:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py in __init__(self, **configs)
    379         client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, metric_group_prefix='producer',
    380                              wakeup_timeout_ms=self.config['max_block_ms'],
--> 381                              **self.config)
    382 
    383         # Get auto-discovered version from client if necessary

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py in __init__(self, **configs)
    237         if self.config['api_version'] is None:
    238             check_timeout = self.config['api_version_auto_timeout_ms'] / 1000
--> 239             self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
    240 
    241     def _can_bootstrap(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py in check_version(self, node_id, timeout, strict)
    890         else:
    891             self._lock.release()
--> 892             raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
    893 
    894     def wakeup(self):

NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

The code worked just fine but out of nowhere it just stopped working for whatever reason.
Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Please show that kafka is running

Answer (score 14):

I had the same error and I solved it by specifying the API version on the function KafkaProducer. Here is a sample from my code.

Please specify the version of your kafka-python library if the error persists.

```
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers=#####,
    client_id=######,
    value_serializer=JsonSerializer.serialize,
    api_version=(0, 10, 1)
)
```

For the API version, you should put your Kafka version.

Comment: Adding the api version fixed the issue . Thanks.